# Updating primary key record on foreign key record change

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a one to many relation with Postgres.
The primary key entity LUT is dependent on its child entities.
I am looking for a way to cascade changes in the foreign key entities to the primary entity and update its LUT.

Since there can be many changes a solution with some kind of debounce will be better.

Example structure:
Table of primary entities:

Buildings

| id | address | name | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxxx | aaa | 2022-08-26 09:23:57.768+00 |
| 2 | qqqqq | bbb | 2022-08-27 10:20:57.768+00 |
| 3 | wwwww | ccc | 2022-08-27 09:20:57.768+00 |

Table of child entities - building_id is foreign to the buildings table:

Floors

| id | building_id | rooms_number | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 2022-08-26 08:24:54.668+00 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2022-07-25 11:25:37.712+00 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-08-23 07:07:21.432+00 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 2022-08-29 09:19:58.765+00 |

I need that every time a floor is being updated, the updated_at of its building (foreign key entity) will also be updated as well i.e. its updated_at will update as well.

Trying to achieve it with DB functionality and not in the code. one of the issues is that many floors can be updated simultaneously. This is why I asked about debouncing for not having many updates of the building.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please update your question to show the table structures, some sample data and an example of the type of change you are talking about. It is not clear how a parent could be dependent on a child or what change to a child would affect a parent and therefore need it to be updated

Comment: you have to implement after update trigger on table of child entities where you can update your parent record(s), more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options:

1. Keep `updated_at` column in building and develop triggers to synchronize the `update_at` columns between `building` and `floor` tables. This is the process you currently have.  
   Advantage: `Updated_at` column for building easily accessible through simple direct query.  
   Disadvantage: Requires additional code, perhaps quite complicated, to select the correct `updated_at` from floor table. Consider, initial floor entry contained incorrect building_id. What does the trigger need to do when corrected. How about a delete from floor; might it contain the current building `updated_at`? .
2. Do not actually store the `updated_at` column on the building table.
   Instead create a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that derives the latest `updated_at` column from `floors` table.  
   Advantage: No further action (code) required on DML operations.
   `Updated_at` column for `buildings` always shows latest floor updated value (if any).  
   Disadvantage: Cannot issue DML directly against `building` as it is a view (keeping same name) as the underlying table has a different name. This would require [Instead of](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) triggers to update actual table or each developer to have knowledge of the underlying table.

IMHO option 2 is by far the superior. It follows the basic relational model dictate of *do not store what is derivable*. Is it without issues? Clearly not, you will probably want to build `instead of` triggers. And there could be others. See here a [short example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5c92546adb625e603003a5581560217.) containing each option.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your foreign key relationships have ON UPDATE CASCADE specified, and the foreign key will automatically update to match the primary key.

Comment: Thanks, but cascading updates the child entities, I need to update the parent (primary key) update time on the child update

Comment: it's not related to the keys in any case, please read the question with more care